# asp.net display textbox on item checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

So just starting out with asp.net... I want to display my textbox when my checkbox is checked, but this doesn't seem to be working. I also tried with the visible property, but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong exactly?

Code:

```
    protected void checked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text.Style["display"] = "block";
    }
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>gehuwd/samenwonend<asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="checked" OnCheckedChanged="checked_CheckedChanged"></asp:checkbox>
        </p>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AutoPostBack` property for checkbox and set it to `true`:

```
<asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="checked" OnCheckedChanged="checked_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:checkbox>
```

Comment: OK. That's good. By the way, to make it disable or hide, you can use Visible = false by default in the ASP.NET tag. Then finally in the event TextBoxID.Visible = true.

Comment: Yea that's what I tried the first time, but that didn't work. I didn't know about the postback, so it would've worked too if I did :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use add css property of textbox in c# as given below. If your checkbox `OnCheckedChanged` is not working then you can set property `AutoPostBack`  is true in checkbox.

```
protected void checked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    text.Attributes.Add("display","block");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this completely client side, using jQuery or javascript.Making a post back to the server everytime you need to change the visual appearance of your HTML can put unnecessary strain on the server and have a negative effect on the user experience by slowing down the overall performance of your site.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var id = "<%: text.ClientID %>";
            id = "#" + id;
            $(id).hide();

            $("#chkShowHide").change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $(id).show();
                }
                else{
                    $(id).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input id="chkShowHide" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Show\Hide<br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
```